# D3: scale data on the x-axis every 7 years

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a d3 project where I want to include all my dates but only on certain intervals. Right now it displays everything which is too cluttered.  I only want to display the labels on the x axis every 7 years. so for example 1947, 1954, 1961, 1968, etc. Pease help and thank you in advance.

Here is my code:

```
loadData = ()=> {
  req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open("GET", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json" , true);
  req.send();
  req.onload= ()=>{
      json = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
      //dynmaic height
    /*var margin = {top: 20, right: 200, bottom: 0, left: 20},
        width = 300,
        height = datajson.length * 20 + margin.top + margin.bottom;*/
      //create measurements
      const margin = 60
      const width = 1000 - margin;
      const height = 600 - margin;
      const maxYScale = d3.max(json.data, (d) => d[1]);

      //date formatter
      const formatDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d"); //convert from string to date format
      const parseDate = d3.timeFormat("%Y"); //format date to cstring


      //create svg
      const svg = d3.select("svg");
      const chart = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(${margin}, ${margin})`);


      //y-axis: split charts into 2 equal parts using scaling function
      const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([height, 0]) //length
        .domain([0, maxYScale]); //content

      //create x-axis
      const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

      //append y-axis
      chart.append("g")
        .call(yAxis);



       //create x-scale
      const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
        .range([0, width]) //length
        //.domain(json.data.filter((date, key) => { return (key % 20 === 0)}).map((d)=> parseDate(formatDate(d[0])))) 
        .domain(json.data.map((d)=> parseDate(formatDate(d[0])))) 
        .padding(0.2);

      //create x-axis
      const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

      //append x-axis
      chart.append("g")
        .attr(`transform`, `translate(0, ${height})`)
        .call(xAxis);

      //make bars
      chart.selectAll("rect")
        .data(json.data)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", (d) => xScale(parseDate(formatDate(d[0]))))
        .attr("y", (d) => yScale(d[1]))
        .attr("height", (d) => height - yScale(d[1]))
        .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())



   } 
}

loadData();
```

Here is my codepen:
[codepen](https://codepen.io/roger1891/pen/rRxRRz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just going to answer my own question as I found the solution. In order to set intervals in the x axis I simply used **tickValues**. Then I used my scale and a filter function to filter the intervals based on the data I had. Below you may find the answer.

```
const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
        .tickValues(xScale.domain().filter(function(d) { return (d % 7 === 0)}));
```